# Amazon ELB in Australia does not work reliably

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have a user in Australia who cannot access our site.  Our site sits behind an AWS ELB which seems to work fine.  While troubleshooting his machine remotely I can see that ELB issues two IP addresses - one of which he always gets a time out.

So every request to our site gets one of the two IP addresses - 50.x.x.x or 184.x.x.x.  If he gets the 50.x.x.x the site doesn't work.

Curious, I decided to verify this by checking a separate company who I know uses ELB.  The same problem happens. Two IP's are issued randomly between requests.  The site works only on one of them.

How in the heck can I fix this?  What are my options?  I figure it would be easier to ask here vs. AWS.

Comment: Multiple addresses is normal, but the one unresponsive address can occur due to a misconfiguration of your ELB... but it would impact ALL users who get the "bad" IP, if this is the case.  Have you confirmed that the ELB is responding correctly if you connect directly to each IP?

Comment: Is the ISP common to both these clients? Who is the ISP? Sounds like a routing issue at the ISP end. We use ELB extensively in Australia with 50.x addresses without any problems.

Comment: As a hacky workaround have the user enter an /etc/hosts or equivalent setting for the 184 address to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like their network routes are not working correctly.  Have them try a traceroute and see where it goes.

But that's for informational purposes.

His ISP is the entity responsible for the routing, he should report the problem to them and they should fix it pronto.